# How to name the column of Pandas dataframe with only one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns, one of them is `co`. I can rename this column with `rename()` but if I select the `co` column and create a new dataframe with it, then it loses it's name and I'm unable to assign a new column name. How could I do that?

Works:

```
data = data.rename(columns={'co':'BCH/USDT'})
print(data)

                             id    market  BCH/USDT         vo
dt                                                            
2020-01-19 00:00:00+00:00  1910  BCH/USDT    338.79  305020.88
2020-01-18 00:00:00+00:00   256  BCH/USDT    367.98  251207.19
2020-01-17 00:00:00+00:00   255  BCH/USDT    326.58  395293.42
2020-01-16 00:00:00+00:00   254  BCH/USDT    340.00  247311.30
2020-01-15 00:00:00+00:00   253  BCH/USDT    348.35  498653.96
```

Rename doesn't works:

```
df = data['co']
df.columns = ['BCH/USDT']
print(df)

dt
2020-01-19 00:00:00+00:00    338.79
2020-01-18 00:00:00+00:00    367.98
2020-01-17 00:00:00+00:00    326.58
2020-01-16 00:00:00+00:00    340.00
2020-01-15 00:00:00+00:00    348.35
```

Same problem with:

```
df.rename(columns={'':'BCH/USDT'}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: You slice the Series, so technically it doesn't lose its name, it's just displayed at the bottom: `Name: co, dtype: float64`. You can rename it with `df = df.rename('BCH/USDT')`. Though I'd opt to use the variable `s` as it's really a Series, not a DataFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are slice a `series` not sub `dataframe` , adding `[]`

```
df = data[['co']]
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had a new dataframe but I hadn't!

Answer (score 2):

you can name your `pd.Series` if you want

```
df.name = 'BCH/USDT'
```

this name will be kept if you join/merge this `pd.Series` with another `pd.DataFrame` and the column name will be the series name

or

you could transform a `pd.Series` to 1 column `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df = df.to_frame('BCH/USDT')
```